# vb.net increment string with prefix

Tags: vb.net, string, integer, increment

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I can't find exactly what I'm after.

I have a string which has a string, then a dash, then a number, e.g. "TERM-01" which happens to be the name of an electrical terminal in a switchboard.
I want to increment it to "TERM-02", "TERM-03" etc.

I have come up with this:

```
TermNo = CStr(Mid(TermNo, 1, InStr(TermNo, "-")) & (CInt(Mid(TermNo, InStr(TermNo, "-") + 1, TermNo.Length - InStr(TermNo, "-")) + 1)))
```

Which seems to work fairly well, however I need to increment the number including the 0, so 08, 09, 10 instead of 8,9,10.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the standard Substring method to point to the part where the number starts, convert it to an integer and add your increment. The trick to return the number with the 0 prefix is done using the [format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dwhawy9k(v=vs.100).aspx) D2

```
Dim TermNo = "TERM-01"
for i = 1 To 15
    Dim value = "TERM-" + (Convert.ToInt32( _ 
                           TermNo.SubString( _ 
                           TermNo.IndexOf("-"))) + i) _
                           .ToString("D2")
    Console.WriteLine(value)
Next
```

This could also be written using a Regex expression in a more readable way

```
Dim TermNo = "TERM-01"
for i = 1 To 15
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(TermNo, "\d+", i.ToString("D2")))
Next
```

Comment: Its nice to see someone still uses Format Specifier!

Answer (score 0):

If you always have a dash, simply split the string on the dash and deal with the pieces individually.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx